# Cannot release Direct3D buffer from swap chain for resize

Tags: resize, uwp, directx-11, direct3d11

I am struggling re-sizing a buffer when my windows changes. Every part of the process works as expected for exception of this one.

```
// in MyGame.h - 
private:
    ComPtr<ID3D11RenderTargetView> gRenderTarget;
...


// handle resize method:
void MyGame::UpdateBackbufferSize(UINT pWidth, UINT pHeight) {

    /* 1. Clear render targets from device context */
    gDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(0, 0, 0);

    /* 2. Release Rendering Target */
    gRenderTarget->Release(); // ! CANNOT ACCESS client.h private Release()

    /* 3. Resize buffer */
    gSwapchain->ResizeBuffers(
        0,
        pWidth,
        pHeight,
        DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN,
        0
        );

    /* 4. Reset the buffer as target view */ 
    ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> backBuffer;
    gSwapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), &backBuffer);
    gDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(backBuffer.Get(), nullptr,     &gRenderTarget);
    backBuffer.Get()->Release();

    /* 5. Set the new render target 
    gDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, gRenderTarget.GetAddressOf(), nullptr);

    /* 6. Reset view port */
    D3D11_VIEWPORT vp = { 0 };
    vp.Width = pWidth;
    vp.Height = pHeight;
    vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    vp.TopLeftX = 0;
    vp.TopLeftY = 0;
    gDeviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &vp);

}
```

If I try

```
gRenderTarget->Release();
```

I would get a "cannot access Release() from "RemoveIUnknownBase" ... inaccessible...

I also tried

```
ID3D11RenderTargetView* rtv = gRenderTarget.Get();
rtv->Release();
```

but I get some sort of access violation... I don't get it.

This is what is happening:

Right after start up:

[image]

After resizing:

[image]

View port changes, yet the buffer remains the same.

Besides of @Chuck suggestions, I also got a global ComPtr for the back buffer to call .Reset() on it as well, just in case, right after calling .Reset() on gRenderTarget

Thanks.

Comment: ``pWidth`` and ``pHeight`` are poor choices of names. While Microsoft has generally moved away from [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) since technologies like Intellisense and C++ type-safety does a lot better job, most readers are going to assume these are pointers which they are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if you **enabled the [Direct3D Debug device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx)**, you would've gotten a debugger message which states the problem is that you have outstanding reference counts on your back-buffer. They should all be released so the count is zero before the swap chain is resized.

Second, you are failing to check the HRESULT of COM functions that return them. One of them failed, and you didn't check it so a later pointer was null.
**Always check the HRESULT value!** If it was safe to ignore it, the function would return void. You can do this with the `SUCCEEDED` macro, the `FAILED` macro, or for fatal fast fail in programs built with C++ Exception Handling  (`/EHsc`) enabled as is typical in universal Windows apps, you'd use a helper like [DX::ThrowIfFailed](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed). See also [Error Handling in COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485842.aspx).

Third, you are following best practice by using a smart pointer instead of raw pointers with manual calls to `Release`. [Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) is the natural choice for universal Windows apps. **However, you don't ever call `Release` on them and you certainly never call `Get()->Release`**. If you want to manually release a ComPtr, you use `Reset`.

The real nut of your problem is that `gDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(0, 0, 0);` does **not** unbind the render target. This function takes an array of render targets for dealing with Multiple Render Targets. You are basically telling it "change the depth stencil view to null, but leave the render targets alone".

**So with all that mind, you probably want something more like:**

```
/* 1. Clear render targets from device context */
// Clear the previous window size specific context.
ID3D11RenderTargetView* nullViews [] = { nullptr };
gDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(_countof(nullViews), nullViews, nullptr);

/* 2. Release Rendering Target */
gRenderTarget.Reset();
gDeviceContext->Flush();

/* 3. Resize buffer */
HRESULT hr = gSwapchain->ResizeBuffers(
    0,
    pWidth,
    pHeight,
    DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN,
    0
    );

if (hr == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED || hr == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET)
{
    // If the device was removed for any reason, a new device and swap chain will need to be created.
    // TODO!
}
else
{
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(hr);
}

/* 4. Reset the buffer as target view */ 
ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> backBuffer;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(gSwapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), &backBuffer));
DX::ThrowIfFailed(gDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(backBuffer.Get(), nullptr, &gRenderTarget));

/* 5. Set the new render target 
gDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, gRenderTarget.GetAddressOf(), nullptr);

/* 6. Reset view port */
D3D11_VIEWPORT vp = { 0 };
vp.Width = pWidth;
vp.Height = pHeight;
vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
vp.TopLeftX = 0;
vp.TopLeftY = 0;
gDeviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &vp);
```

> I recommend you take a look at the [Direct3D UWP Game](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/12/17/direct3d-game-visual-studio-templates-redux.aspx) VS template and the [DirectX Tool Kit tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Note that you need to release all uses of the back-buffer before the `Flush` including references like from Direct2D.

Comment: Hello @Chuck Walbourn, thanks for your thorough answer. +1. On the other hand, please see my edit of the question for further help. My view port is changing, as it was before, yet the buffer is not being resized after your edits for better code handling. Amy help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any obvious reason for it, but you should get DEBUG messages or HRESULT failures if you have some other problem. You should try moving the ``Flush`` down to below the ``Reset`` as I've edited the code to show--deferred resource destruction is tricksie and that's why the ``Flush`` call is there in the first place.

Comment: The HRESULT I am getting is 887a0001 which indicates "DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL". I checked docs to make sure I wasn't missing naythign out and indeed, they seem to be correct. I am even getting a DXGI_SWAL_CHAIN_DESC1 to replicate settings and still nothing. This is because the Swap Chain original DESC was created with Scaling DXGI_SCALING_NONE ... I should have chekced there first, i just did not know.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn The HRESULT I am getting is 887a0001 which indicates "DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL". Same here followed your guidelines and the note.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
backBuffer->Release();
```

Comment: Can you pls explain or elaborate it more than just one word answer?

Comment: That won't even compile. Please see my question for details. I tried that and it is marked as inaccessible (private)

Comment: Read the answer of Chuck carefully. "Third, you are following best practice by using a smart pointer instead of raw pointers with manual calls to Release. Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr is the natural choice for universal Windows apps. However, you don't ever call Release on them and you certainly never call Get()->Release. If you want to manually release a ComPtr, you use Reset."